# Nesting include_once problems

Tags: php

Here is my directory tree:

- /

  - index.php
- include/

  - functions.php
  - head.php
  - connect.php
- sub/

  - index.php

In my head.php and connect.php both have:

```
include_once 'include/functions.php';
```

My index.php in the root folder includes these two: head.php and connect.php like this:

```
include_once 'include/connect.php';
include_once 'include/head.php;'
```

However, when my index.php in sub/ includes functions.php and head.php, they would fail to also include functions.php.
Here's how I included in the sub/index.php:

```
include_once '../include/connect.php';
include_once '../include/head.php';
```

If I change in the head.php and connect.php to: **include_once '../include/functions.php';**

The sub/index.php would include everything normally but the index.php in the root would fail to load the functions.php.

How can I fix this?

PHP version: 5.2.*

Comment: I **think** there is an error in your `head.php` and `connect.php` include statements.  `include_once 'include/functions.php';` should be `include_once 'functions.php';` because head.php and connect.php are in the same directory as functions.php? correct me if im wrong :P

Comment: @vincent-wilkie Thanks! This is what it's been having problems with... Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

### The Error

---

Include statement error in `head.php` and `connect.php`

`include_once 'include/functions.php';`

---

### The Fix

---

`include_once 'functions.php';`

**OR**

`include_once __DIR__ . 'functions.php'; //PHP 5.3 or higher`

**OR**

`include_once dirname(__FILE__) . 'functions.php'; //PHP 5.2 or lower`

---

### The Reason

---

`head.php` and `connect.php` are located in the same folder as `functions.php`

As suggested by @Schleis, using [`__DIR__`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) (PHP 5.3+) or [`dirname(__FILE__);`](http://www.php.net/dirname) (PHP 5.2-) will allow for relative file includes.

Comment: Thanks! Voted and checked this.

Answer (score 5):

Use the constant `__DIR__` in your include statements and then move relative to that.  So in sub/index.php you would do `include_once __DIR__ . '../include/connect.php'`

The `__DIR__` is a constant that is the directory of the file that you are in.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

If you are using php < v5.3, you can use `dirname(__FILE__)` to get the same thing.

Comment: `__DIR__` added as of PHP 5.3.0 :)

Comment: See update, you can use `dirname(__FILE__)` to get the directory in previous php versions

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to set your web project root directory in every file using [`chdir()`](http://php.net/chdir) function, so you don't need to think about it where are you currently located and how many back-dirs `../` you need.

Use example:

```php
chdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define constant for include path in root file and then use that constant in all other files:

```
define( "INCLUDE_PATH",  dirname(__FILE__) . '/include/' );

// some other file
include_once INCLUDE_PATH . 'functions.php';
```

It is good practice to have one file like `config.php` in the root folder where are defined global settings like include paths etc. That way you do not have to care about relative paths anymore, and if in the future you decide to change the folder structure, instead of changing the paths in all files just change the include constant.